# "When we pass an anonymous function somewhere, the value of "this" is lost". What does this mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm following a tutorial on Javascript and ES6 and in the example below I get an error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'teamName' of undefined."

The tutor explains it as: "Whenever we pass an anonymous function somewhere in our code base, the value of `this` inside of that function is lost!" What does he mean by that? Shouldn't `this` hold the object making the call and wouldn't that mean `team.teamName` which would return `Avengers` here? I'm confused.
Also, how is the issue fixed when we use `.bind(this)`?

```
const team = {
 members: ['Tony', 'Peter'],
 teamName: 'Avengers',
 teamSummary: function() {
    return this.members.map(function(member) {

    return `${member} is a member of ${this.teamName}`;

  });

 }

};

team.teamSummary();
```

Comment: `function(member) {` <- this function has a new context

Comment: I hope the duplicates provide an understandable explanation, if you still got questions feel free to ask :)

Comment: *"Shouldn't `this` hold the object making the call"* but in a context like `somefunction(callback){ ... callback(); }` what is the object that is making the call to `callback()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `arrow function (=>)` like as shown below. They help in retaining the `this` that called the function.

```
const team = {
 members: ['Tony', 'Peter'],
 teamName: 'Avengers',
 teamSummary: function() {
    return this.members.map((member) => {

    return `${member} is a member of ${this.teamName}`;

  });

 }

};

team.teamSummary();
```

Please read this [blog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem) for more fixes for the same solution

Comment: Hey, thanks! I know the solution to the problem. I just wanted to know why it is showing the error.

Comment: Please read the blog i mentioned in editted post. It will explain evrything to you